# Flood fill space complexity

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I've searched around but been unable to find an answer anywhere.

How much extra space is required for the four-way flood fill algorithms using a queue or stack?

Answer (score 0):

The simple 4-way recursive algorithm is pathological and consumes O(N) bytes of stack space where N is the number of pixels to fill. The queue method is a lot better, in the normal case you have a ring of O(sqrt(N)) pixels, it is possible to devise an intricate fill pattern where you have more pixels in the queue and I'm not sure what the upper limit is.

Comment: The queue method has the same worst-case complexity as 4-way recursive.

Answer (score 0):

space-wise, you just need one more copy about your original matrix. so the complexity is just O(mn)